# set alpha without effecting the shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with the shadow is being effected by the alpha

how do i set the alpha without effecting the shadow ?

I have tried to reset the alpha after drawing the rectangle but no use..

```js
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

ctx.shadowColor = "#F08"
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;

ctx.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid gray;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `strokeStyle` property, or `fillStyle` if drawing filled shapes. Example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

var offset = 1000;

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(-offset, 0);
ctx.shadowOffsetX = offset;
ctx.shadowColor = "#F08";
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
ctx.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
ctx.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid gray;"></canvas>
```

Comment: using "rgba" is effecting the shadow too :(

Comment: I edited it a bit, is it what you want? If so I will explain,.

Comment: clever hack to get only the shadow ;-) But offset should probably be a it more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to draw your shape in 3 pass:

1. draw your shadow and the stroke at alpha 1.
2. erase your stroke with globalCompositeOperation modes
3. redraw your low alpha stroke

But for step 2 to work correctly, we have to account for the stroke overlapping between x - lineWidth and x + linewidth, thus creating antialiasing with a lineWidth set to 1. To counter it, we can translate the whole context by 0.5px on both axis.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");

draw();

async function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  if (waiter.checked) await wait(500);
  // we need to translate by 0.5 for the stroke to not be antialiased
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5);
  // first pass with shadow
  ctx.shadowColor = "#F08"
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
  ctx.rect(10, 10, 60, 60);
  ctx.stroke();

  if (waiter.checked) await wait(1000);
  // second pass to clear the stroke
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"; // remove shadow
  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.stroke();

  if (waiter.checked) await wait(1000);
  // third pass to draw the low alpha stroke
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  ctx.stroke();

  // reset to default
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

function wait(t) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t));
}

waiter.onchange = draw;
```

```html
<label> wait between draw steps<input type="checkbox" id="waiter"></label>
<canvas style="border: 1px solid gray;"></canvas>
```